# Lock-free programming without linked lists

Tags: c++, multithreading, linked-list

I have read on multiple occasions that linked lists are, at best, a niche data structure ill-suited for general purpose use due to their poor cache locality. Yet almost every example of a lock-free data structure I have seen uses a linked list. Both *C++ Concurrency in Action* and *The 
Art of Multiprocessor Programming*, for instance, use a linked list in their implementation of a lock-free stack and queue.

Are there better alternatives to linked lists when designing lock-free containers, such as stacks and queues?

Comment: A circular buffer is a common data structure that can offer both lock-freedom and locality. (But it usually has a bounded capacity.)

Comment: You can use deques, which are a mix between linked lists and arrays. The think is that lock free linked lists are simple to implement meanwhile other, more complex, data structs have many corner cases that you have to take into account.

Comment: @JorgeBellón Do you have any resources on how a lock-free STL-like deque can be implemented? It seems pretty difficult to me.

Comment: I am afraid hardware instructions to provide atomicity are not cache friendly, so changing data structure may not help

Comment: @Slava algorithms that cause contention are not cache friendly due to the ping-pong effect of the cache coherence protocol but, if the concept of [lock-free cache-awareness](http://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-17653-1_23) exist, then it will be for a reason.

Comment: @JorgeBellón if the concept of "perpetuum mobile"  exists, then it will be for a reason?

Comment: @AlessandroPower I know that [Intel Thread Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org) provides several C++ STL-like concurrent structures. You should check them, although I'm not really sure whether they are lock-free or not. However, you should check whether a lock-free data structure is what you need or if it would rather be better to use [spin based locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) if the data structure is only part of the process and not the biggest part of it.

Comment: @Slava Good answer, but there are not perpetual motion machine papers in mechanical engineering conferences.

Comment: @JorgeBellón not everything that have papers on conferences is true. First of all "lock-free" containers are not such, just locks moved to hardware level. This marketing confusion makes many people thinks that they do not have perfomance penalty.

Comment: You could implement a linked list using an array.  This will keep the nodes local so that some of them can fit into a cache line or the cache memory.

Comment: @Sava linked-lists can be implemented without locks using atomic compare and swap. They are not suitable for low contention because their best-case performance is worse, but due to their fine synchronization granularity they can perform better than the classic coarse locks when lots of threads are simultaneously accessing. [Hardware locks](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-the-monitor-and-mwait-streaming-simd-extensions-3-instructions/) are different.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there better alternatives to linked lists when designing lock-free containers

Yes, probably, for some purposes. The linked list is just the simplest thing that generalises well to many applications.

---

If you use a singly-linked list (in the simplest case), you can populate a node with no synchronisation issues at all (*= multiple threads can populate nodes concurrently*), and the only synchronised operation is the head-pointer swap.

So although linked lists aren't otherwise suggested for performance, you can see this generalises to arbitrarily large and complex nodes, and arbitrary numbers of both producers and consumers.

Compare the circular buffer: if you have multiple producers you need some way to mark part of the buffer reserved (protected from other writes) before it's available for reading. This is because all producers are sharing the same buffer, instead of working on their own nodes. It's workable, but essentially non-atomic, just because you can't prepare *part of a shared buffer* away from the prying eyes of other threads in the same way you can prepare a separate node.

If you have a single producer it's easy, and it does have better locality than a linked list, but it is obviously *less general*.

Answer (score 1):

A linked list doesn't necessarily mean lack of locality. If all nodes in the list have been allocated through a single allocation (malloc in C), then the memory for all nodes will be contiguous, regardless of how nodes point to each other. If sizeof(node) * max_nodes_count is relatively small, it may fit in various cache levels.

Comment: True, but you still have the data dependency, so traversing a linked list even of consecutive adjacently-allocated nodes is still more expensive than traversing a vector (dependent on architecture, YMMV etc.)